# Iterate through positional arguments with clap

Tags: rust, clap

Say I have the following command line:

```
./app foo bar baz
```

I want to get this array out of it:

```
["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

Is there a way to do this in clap, given that the positional arguments can be of arbitrary count?

Comment: Actually, you don't need clap for that. `let args: Vec<String> = env::args().skip(1).collect()` will do the job.

Comment: I want a CLI parser because I also have a flag, `./app foo bar baz --qux`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [values_of](https://docs.rs/clap/2.24.2/clap/struct.ArgMatches.html#method.values_of), you can use it like this:

```
let matches = App::new("My Super Program")
        .arg(Arg::with_name("something")
            .multiple(true))
        .get_matches();

let iterator = matches.values_of("something");
for el in iterator.unwrap() {
    println!("{:?}", el);
};
```

If you don't care about preserving invalid UTF-8 the easier choice is using [values_of_lossy](https://docs.rs/clap/2.24.2/clap/struct.ArgMatches.html#method.values_of_lossy) which returns an actual Vector (`Option<Vec<String>>`) and not an iterator.

```
let arguments = matches.values_of_lossy("something").unwrap();      
println!("{:?}", arguments);
```

Keep in mind that you really should not unwrap the values in your actual program as it will just crash at run-time if the arguments are not supplied. The only exception to this would be arguments that `required(true)` was set on. Their absence would cause a run-time error (with helpful error messages) when calling `get_matches`.

Comment: The unwrap is ok if we got `required(true)`, right?

Comment: Yes, when the argument is required you get a runtime error when calling `get_matches`. So the value not being present could only happen due to a programmer error in which case crashing would be reasonable.

Comment: @EliazBobadilla: If you're gonna edit the code to match clap 3, you should probably also adjust the links to doc.rs. But I think having both versions of the code around would be good. Maybe post a separate answer?

Comment: FWIW, Right now I'd love to see a separate answer for the clap 3 derive syntax.